# Set proper XML namespaces after classes generated by xsd.exe

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I generated c# classes from an xsd with xsd.exe tool. In the original schema the namespaces are the follow:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

The root in the generated class is as follows:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]    
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff")]    
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff", IsNullable = false)]
```

My problem is that after I serialize this class I got an XML with the following schema:

```
<someThing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff">
```

But what I need is this:

```
<tns:someThing xmlns:tns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff">
```

And to make things more interesting I need the tns: prefix in the root and some of other nodes. Something like this:

```
<tns:someThing xmlns:tns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff">
<tns:header>
    <tns:request>id-707</tns:request>
    <tns:timestamp>2015-01-29T12:18:29+01:00</tns:timestamp>
</tns:header>
<tns:user>
    <tns:user>myUserName</tns:user> 
    <tns:password>hashedPwd</tns:password>
</tns:user>
<someOperations>
    <someOperation>
         <id>1212</id>
         <name>nameOfThis</name>
    </someOperation>
</someOperations>
</tns:someThing>
```

How can I set these namespaces and prefixes properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your desired output has two identical namespaces, `xmlns:tns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff"` and `xmlns="http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff"`.  This is unnecessary.  However, given that one of the two is the default namespace, the `tns:` prefix is redundant.  Are you sure you need it anyway?

Comment: Yes, the xsd given by the customer requires it. I'm stucked with this issue.

Comment: The xsd requires that the elements be in the specified *namespace*, which they are.  But an XSD doesn't specify how that gets implemented in the XML file.  The prefix is really just a local lookup key to find the actual namespace and has no meaning in and of itself.  In fact `user` and `someOperations` are in the same namespace, it's just the file duplicated lookup keys and one element uses one key while the other uses the other key.

Answer (score 0):

This approach should help with namespace prefix:

```
var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
namespaces.Add("tns", "http://TheXsdGivenSchema.com/SOMETHING/1.0/stuff");
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(entity));
serializer.Serialize( stream, entity, namespaces);
```

Taken from this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ed55114-0f1b-4e54-b597-21fe1a61f06b/add-prefixes-and-namesapce-to-xml-serialization?forum=csharpgeneral